# Reverse right half of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

> reverse second half linkedlist
>   example:
>   even number:
>   2->1->3->4->5->6->7->8 =====> 2->1->3->4->8->7->6->5 ；
>
> odd number: 5->7->8->6->3->4->2 ======> 5->7->8->2->4->3->6, the
>   middle one also need be reversed

```
class ListNode
{
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}


class ReverseRightHalfLinkedList 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        ListNode node1 = new ListNode(1);
        ListNode node2 = new ListNode(2);
        ListNode node3 = new ListNode(3);
        ListNode node4 = new ListNode(4);
        ListNode node5 = new ListNode(5);
        node1.next = node2;
        node2.next = node3;
        node3.next = node4;
        node4.next = node5;

        ListNode res = reverse(node1);//line 31

//      ListNode node = node1;
//      while (node != null)
//      {
//          System.out.println(node.val);
//          node = node.next;
//      }

    }

    public static ListNode reverse(ListNode start)
    {   
        int counter = 0;
        ListNode node = start;
        ListNode pre = start;

        while (node!= null)
        {
            counter += 1;
            node = node.next;           
        }

        for (int i=0; i<counter/2; i++)
        {   
            pre = start;
            start = start.next; 
        }

        ListNode cur = start;

        if (counter%2 ==0)
        {
            while (cur != null)
            {
                ListNode temp = cur.next;
                cur.next = pre;
                pre = cur;
                cur = temp;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            pre = pre.next;
            cur = start.next;

            System.out.println(pre.val);
            System.out.println(cur.val);

            while (cur != null)
            {
                ListNode temp = cur.next;
                cur.next = pre;
                pre = cur;
                cur = temp;


                System.out.println("-----");
                System.out.println(pre.val); // line 90
                System.out.println(cur.val);
                System.out.println("-----");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        return start;

    }
}
```

Firstly, I got an error message.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   ReverseRightHalfLinkedList.reverse(OA2.java:90)   at
>   ReverseRightHalfLinkedList.main(OA2.java:31)

Secondly, I tried to print the order of reversed linked list, it is still in order. It was not reversed.

Please help me to figure out these two problems. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on @passion's idea. I got a more concise code.

```
class ListNode
{
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}


class ReverseRightHalfLinkedList 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        ListNode node1 = new ListNode(2);
        ListNode node2 = new ListNode(1);
        ListNode node3 = new ListNode(3);
        ListNode node4 = new ListNode(4);
        ListNode node5 = new ListNode(5);
        ListNode node6 = new ListNode(6);
        ListNode node7 = new ListNode(7);
        ListNode node8 = new ListNode(8);
        node1.next = node2;
        node2.next = node3;
        node3.next = node4;
        node4.next = node5;
        node5.next = node6;
        node6.next = node7;
        node7.next = node8;


        ListNode res = reverse(node1);

        ListNode node = node1;
        while (node != null)
        {
            System.out.println(node.val);
            node = node.next;
        }

    }

    public static ListNode reverse(ListNode start)
    {   
        int counter = 0;
        ListNode node = start;
        ListNode pre = start;

        ListNode result = start;

        while (node!= null)// for count how many elements in linked list
        {
            counter += 1;
            node = node.next;           
        }

        for (int i=0; i< (counter / 2) ; i++)//no matter counter is even or odd, when it divided by 2, the result is even
        {   
            pre = start;
            start = start.next; 
        }


        ListNode temp = null;
        ListNode preNext = null;// this variable is used to track the next val behind pre
        // for example, 2->1->3->4->5->6->7->8
        // at this moment, pre:4, start:5
        // I treated 5->6->7->8 as an independent linkedlist
        // I reversed the linkedlist 
        // Finally, set the pre node's next value to the reversed linkedlist's head
        // The first half and second half have been connected together


        while (start != null)
        {
            temp = start.next;
            start.next = preNext;
            preNext = start;
            start = temp;
        }
        pre.next = preNext;

        return start;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need reverse right half list , so you need to save last node of the left half and the header of the list , so than when right half get reversed , you can link them with the left half and return the whole list .

I have change your reverse method :

```
    public static ListNode reverse(ListNode start)
    {   
        int counter = 0;
        ListNode node = start;
        ListNode pre = start;

        ListNode result = start;

        while (node!= null)
        {
            counter += 1;
            node = node.next;           
        }

        int end = counter % 2 == 0 ? counter / 2 : (counter- 1) / 2 ;

        for (int i=0; i< end ; i++)
        {   
            pre = start;
            start = start.next; 
        }


        ListNode tlist = null,temp ;

        while(start != null){
            temp = start.next;

            if(tlist == null){
            tlist = start;
            start.next = null;
            }else{
            start.next = tlist;

            tlist = start;
            }

            start = temp;

        }

        pre.next = tlist;

        return start;

    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Basing on your idea, I got a more concise code. Again, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you understand.

```
class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Node head = new Node("Sameer");

        //Adding data to my linked list
        Node temp = addNode("Monica", head);
        temp = addNode("Doug", temp);
        temp = addNode("Eric", temp);
        temp = addNode("Charlie", temp);
        temp = addNode("Dan", temp);
        temp = addNode("Enrique", temp);
        temp = addNode("Ankitha", temp);
        addNode("Chad", temp);

        SolveMidLinkedList(head);
    }

    //method to add a node to the linked list
    static Node addNode(String str, Node node) {
        Node newNode = new Node(str);
        node.link = newNode;
        return newNode;
    }

    //method to reverse the right hald of the linkedlist
    static void SolveMidLinkedList(Node head) {
        int LinkedListSize = 0;
        Node temp = head;
        Node LastEle = null, MiddleEle = null, temp1 = null, temp2 = null;

        //While loop to find the size of the linkedlist and also to find the last element in the linkedlist
        while (temp != null) {
            LastEle = temp;
            temp = temp.link;
            LinkedListSize++;
        }

        //Printing the names
        temp = head;
        System.out.println("Before rearranging the linked list");
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println(temp.name);
            temp = temp.link;
        }

        //The main procedure
        temp = head;
        int iCount = 1;
        while (temp != null) {
            //Not changing the order of first half of the linked list
            if (iCount <= (LinkedListSize / 2)) {
                MiddleEle = temp;
            } else {
                //Reversing the order of second half(right side half) of the linked list.
                temp2 = temp.link;
                temp.link = temp1;
                temp1 = temp;
            }
            temp = temp.link;
            iCount++;
        }
        //At the end asssigning the middle element to the last element of the linked list.
        MiddleEle.link = LastEle;

        //Printing the names
        temp = head;
        System.out.println("After rearranging the linked list");
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println(temp.name);
            temp = temp.link;
        }

    }
}

//General definition of Node in a linked list.
class Node {
    Node link = null;
    String name;
    Node(String str) {
        this.name = str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package javaapplication2;

class LinkedList {

    static Node head;

    static class Node {

        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    Node rev(Node node) {
        Node prev = null;
        Node current = node;
        Node next = null;
        while (current != null) {
            next = current.next;
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
        node = prev;
        return node;
    }

    Node reverse(Node node) {
        int count =0;
        Node doo = node;
        Node mid_pre = node;
        Node mid = node;
        while(doo.next != null){
            if((count & 1) == 1){
                //   mid_pre = mid;
                mid = mid.next;
            }
            doo = doo.next;
            count++;
        }
        // System.out.println(" midd ddddd :"+mid_pre.data+" "+mid.data);
        mid.next = rev(mid.next);
        return node;
    }

    void printList(Node node) {
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            node = node.next;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.head = new Node(1);
        list.head.next = new Node(2);
        list.head.next.next = new Node(3);
        list.head.next.next.next = new Node(4);
        list.head.next.next.next.next = new Node(5);
        list.head.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(6);

        ////  1 2 3 4 5 6
        System.out.println("Given Linked list");
        list.printList(head);
        head = list.reverse(head);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Reversed linked list ");
        list.printList(head);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something very straightforward. We know the size of the list. We can use `list.get(counter)` to iterate from the end to the centre. There was a bit of challenge when the list size was even or odd but its doable.

```
public static void reverseFromEndToCentre() {
    List list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));

    int midOfList = (int)Math.ceil(list.size() / 2);
    int lenthOfList = list.size();

    int counterFirstHalf =0;
    while(counterFirstHalf<midOfList){
        System.out.println(list.get(counterFirstHalf));
        counterFirstHalf++;
    }

    int counterSecondHalf = lenthOfList;
    while( counterSecondHalf > counterFirstHalf){
        counterSecondHalf--;
        System.out.println(list.get(counterSecondHalf ));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to reverse second half(right) of linked list.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
int data;
struct Node* next;
};

void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{

struct Node* new_node=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
new_node->data=new_data;
new_node->next=NULL;

struct Node* last=*head_ref;

if(*head_ref==NULL){
    *head_ref=new_node;
    return;
}

while(last->next!=NULL)
    last=last->next;

last->next=new_node;
return;
}

int display(struct Node* n)
{
int m=0;
printf("\n");
while(n!=NULL)
{
    printf(" %d ",n->data);
    n=n->next;
    m=m+1;
}
return m;
}

void reverse(struct Node** head_ref, int mid)
{
if(*head_ref==NULL)
{
    printf("\nEmpty List cannot be reversed");
    return;
}

struct Node* last=*head_ref;
struct Node* second_last;
struct Node* beg=*head_ref;
int c=1;
while(c<=mid){
    second_last=last;
    last=last->next;
    c=c+1;
}

struct Node* prev=NULL;
struct Node* current=last;
struct Node* next;

while(current != NULL)
{
    next=current->next;
    current->next=prev;
    prev=current;
    current=next;
}
*head_ref=beg;
second_last->next=prev;

}

int main()
{
int size;
struct Node* head=NULL;
int i,mid;
for(i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    append(&head,rand()%19 +1);
}
size=display(head);
printf("\n Size of linked list: %d",size);

if(size%2==0)
    mid=(size+1)/2;
else
    mid=size/2;

reverse(&head, mid);
display(head);
return 0;

}
```